# Parsing probably invalid YAML with PyYaml

Tags: python, yaml, puppet, pyyaml, hiera

I would like to parse a puppet related yaml config with pyyaml. Unforunately it seems that pyyaml is unable to parse some of the YAML files because of this part:

```
base::files:

  /var/log/fpm:
    ensure: 'directory'
    mode: '777'

  /etc/nginx/ssl/cert:
   ensure: 'directory'

  /apps:
   ensure: 'directory'
   owner: user
   group: user

  ['/apps/ecert-public', '/apps/ecert-public/config', '/apps/ecert-public/releases']:
    ensure: 'directory'
    owner: 'user'
    group: 'user'

  ['/apps/site-public', '/apps/site-public/config', '/apps/site-public/releases']:
    ensure: 'directory'
    owner: 'user'
    group: 'user'
```

The problem are the mappings with multiple values (inside the square brackets). I get the following error message while trying to parse this part with pyyaml:

> while constructing a mapping   in
>   "/hieradata/node/wc-de.yaml",
>   line 133, column 3 found unhashable key   in
>   "/hieradata/node/wc-de.yaml",
>   line 212, column 3

Some YAML validators say this is valid YAML (like: http://www.yamllint.com/) but most of them I've tried have also problems to parse this part. Has anyone an idea how I can solve this issue with pyyaml? **Unfortunately I can not change the YAML itself, so I need a solution to parse it how it is.**

Comment: Any mapping can have multiple values. What you have there is a mapping with key that is not a scalar but a  sequence, that is valid YAML, but one of the things PyYAML cannot handle.

Comment: YAML places no limitation on mapping keys other than that they be unique.  In particular, it does not require them to be scalars.  Nevertheless, I urge you to revisit the question of whether you can modify the YAML.  From its structure, I suspect that it could be rewritten in a way that means the same thing to the Puppet module that consumes it, but is not as challenging to YAML parsers.

Comment: @Anthon, many YAML processors fail on the OP's valid code. *Why* they fail is not really relevant.  You may choose the adjective you like to describe this situation, but I choose "challenging".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is perfectly valid YAML. It is PyYAML that is the problem. Like all other YAML processors that fail to load this, that I know about, it can *parse* that YAML without problems (and *compose* if the processor implements that step), but fail during the *constructing* step of the loading process.

If you would use `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package) and have your input
in the file `input.yaml`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

file_name = Path('input.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(file_name)
print(data['base::files'][('/apps/ecert-public', '/apps/ecert-public/config', '/apps/ecert-public/releases')]['ensure'])
print('\n-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-\n')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
directory

-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-

base::files:

  /var/log/fpm:
    ensure: directory
    mode: '777'

  /etc/nginx/ssl/cert:
    ensure: directory

  /apps:
    ensure: directory
    owner: user
    group: user


  [/apps/ecert-public, /apps/ecert-public/config, /apps/ecert-public/releases]:
    ensure: directory
    owner: user
    group: user

  [/apps/site-public, /apps/site-public/config, /apps/site-public/releases]:
    ensure: directory
    owner: user
    group: user
```

Comment: I just recognized that your module seems to have a similar problem: An exception occurs if theres a YAML file contains a duplicate mapping - for example if it looks like this:

`
base::test
   value: key

base::test
  value key
`

However... this is not really a problem for me. Just wanted to let you know.

Comment: If you mean duplicate keys in a mapping, that is not allowed in YAML 1.2. In YAML 1.1 the parser is allowed to emit a warning and keep the first key/value pair. You can allow the 1.1 behavior by [setting `allow_duplicate_keys`](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=duplicate#duplicate-keys)